# json.loads fails with "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, unicode, web-scraping, scrapy

I was working on web scraping using Scrapy. Website has embedded json in between `<code>` tag like:

```
<code id="content" style="display:none;"><!--{"content": "text1",...,..., "compute": "text2"}--></code>
```

Using xpath, I was able to extract comment inside `<code>` tag. Used:

```
hxs.select("//code[@id='content']/comment()").extract()
```

After striping comment characters, content has `content = "{"content": "text1",...,..., "compute": "text2"}"`

While building json using json.loads(content), I got `"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"` error.

Also, str(content) throws:

`"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 106512-106513: ordinal not in range(128)"`

value at 106512 is `'\xa7'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(content)`?

Comment: Its big, around 280500 characters. But I have printed value at 106512.

Comment: The `UnicodeEncodeError` might be unrelated to the `ValueError`. Apparently your `content` is `unicode` (not `str`) and `str()` chokes on it, but `json.loads` doesn’t have to. But you can try `json.loads(content.encode('utf-8'))` (or some other appropriate encoding).

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. Even tried json.loads(j.encode('utf-8')) but it throws error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 106512: ordinal not in range(128)". And, charset in request.headers shows 'UTF-8'.

Answer (score 2):

`str(content)` failing for non-ASCII characters is expected and not a problem in itself. `content.encode('utf-8')` would work if what you want is a byte string (though printing it to the console is another matter ([PrintFails](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)). If you just want to show us what's in the variable, print `repr(comment)` to get the Python-syntax representation.

`No JSON object could be decoded` means that `json.loads` can't even begin to find something that looks like JSON at the start of the string, so look at the front of that `repr()` string to see if there are any stray characters or control codes before the `{`.

Comment: Thanks. repr(content) output doesn't show any stray characters. Its output: >> ' \'{"content": "text1",...,..., "compute": "text2"}\' '.

Comment: Is that the output of `print repr(content)`? If it is exactly as you pasted, there are wrapping `'` characters which would prevent it being parsed; if it is just `>>> repr(content)` (ie you have pasted the repr of the repr) then there are leading/trailing spaces I can't account for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, output is from python interpreter. I have put leading/trailing spaces for clarity. print repr(content) shows '{"content": "text1",..,..,"compute":"text2"}'. So, content is proper I mean no stray chars at beginning.

Comment: Confused—`content` should be a Unicode string, as implied by your error trying to `str()` it, and the output of `extract()` being a [list of] unicode string. How are you getting a byte string `content` (no `u''`)?

Answer (score 0):

The string in the json seems to be iso8859 or Windows-1252. \xa7 is § in one of these encoding, while \xc2\xa7 is § in utf-8.